# PulseAudio blacklisting on disconnect

Tags: pulseaudio

I managed to successfully blacklist a device with `module-switch-on-connect` to prevent my audio switching to my docking station each time I connect to it. However, I am sometimes using my bluetooth headeset and when I disconnect it, the solution above doesn't work and the audio happily switches to blacklisted device.

```
## When connecting, blacklist works
sty 10 20:20:25 kotek pulseaudio[23329]: Refusing to switch to blacklisted source alsa_input.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_201405280001-00.iec958-stereo

## but not when disconnecting 
sty 10 20:21:54 kotek pulseaudio[23329]: Lost RFCOMM connection.
sty 10 20:21:55 kotek pulseaudio[23329]: default_sink: 
bluez_sink.00_00_00_00_00_00.a2dp_sink -> alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio_201405280001-00.iec958-stereo
```

Does anyone know if there is workaround for this problem? Otherwise, maybe somebody knows where to find a guide to write my own pa module or code `module-switch-on-connect`? :)

Thanks for help!